# Não consigo filtrar os objetos do array usando Filter

Tags: javascript, json

Estou tentando retornar os objetos de acordo com o id dos generos mas esta sendo retornado um array vazio

```
var filmes = [
    {
    title: 'Primeiro Filme',
    genres: [
        {
        id: 10
      },
      {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Segundo Filme',
    genres: [
        {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 7
      }
    ]
  }
]



var filmesCategorias = filmes.filter(function(filme){
  return filme.genres.id == 3
})

console.log(filmesCategorias)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitua:

```
return filme.genres.id == 3
```

por:

```
return filme.genres.find(x => x.id == 3)
```

codigo funcionando:

```js
var filmes = [
    {
    title: 'Primeiro Filme',
    genres: [
        {
        id: 10
      },
      {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Segundo Filme',
    genres: [
        {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 7
      }
    ]
  }
]



var filmesCategorias = filmes.filter(function(filme){
  return filme.genres.find(x => x.id == 3)
})

console.log(filmesCategorias)
```

Answer (score 2):

O `genres` é um `array` então precisa varrer as posições para a busca do `id==3`, exemplo:

```js
var filmes = [{
    title: 'Primeiro Filme',
    genres: [{
        id: 10
      },
      {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  }, {
    title: 'Segundo Filme',
    genres: [{
        id: 10
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Terceiro Filme',
    genres: [{
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 7
      }
    ]
  }
]



var filmesCategorias = filmes.filter(function(filme) {

  for (i = 0; i < filme.genres.length; i++) {
    if (filme.genres[i].id == 3) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
})

console.log(filmesCategorias)
```

O comando [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) tem a sua compatibilidade a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>**Fonte:** [Array.prototype.filter() - Compatibilidade de Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)</sub>

Já ao utilizar `find` pode simplificar o código, mas, limitar o seu uso em navegadores como tabela exibida logo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>**Fonte:** [Array.prototype.find() - Compatibilidade do Navegador](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)</sub>

---

Uma maneira *sem esses comandos que em algum momento podem limitar o seu uso*, com duas estruturas de repetição pode resolver o mesmo problema, exemplo minimo:

```js
var filmes = [{
    title: 'Primeiro Filme',
    genres: [{
        id: 10
      },
      {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  }, {
    title: 'Segundo Filme',
    genres: [{
        id: 10
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Terceiro Filme',
    genres: [{
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 7
      }
    ]
  }
]

function findFilmeGenresById()
{
    var item = Array();    
    for(i = 0; i < filmes.length; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < filmes[i].genres.length; j++)
        {
          if (filmes[i].genres[j].id == 3)
          {
            item.push(filmes[i]); 
            break;
          }
        }        
    }
    return item;
}

console.log(findFilmeGenresById());
```